# C# Access Struct using String

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a bit stuck with my game. I have a class called Upgradebuttons. From this class I want to access some variables stored in a struct from another class. I can easily access the variables by typing classname.structname.preferedvar but the structname depends on which upgrade as been clicked. So I want to call the struct using a string. I have tried:

```
       MethodInfo method = typeof(Classname).GetMethod(structname);
```

But this only works if it is a void and not a struct. What do I need to do in order to get this working?

```
    public class UpgradeButtons : MonoBehaviour {

       public void somefunction{
          // here i want to have access

      }

 }
```

This is an example of the class I want to have access to:

```
    public class Upgrades: MonoBehaviour {
        public struct Upgrade1{
            public const int Cost = 10;
            public const float Value = 0.1f;
            public static string Naam = "Autoclicker";
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is possible, it sounds like poorly thought out design. Perhaps you could use one common `struct Upgrade` and use the `Name` property to find it at runtime?

Example:

```
public struct Upgrade
{
    public string Name;
    public int Cost;
    public float Value;

    public Upgrade(string name, int cost, float value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Cost = cost;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class UpgradeButtons : MonoBehavior
{
    List<Upgrade> Upgrades = new List<Upgrade>();

    public void CreateButtons()
    {
        Upgrades.Add(new Upgrade("Autoclicker", 10, 0.1f));
        //etc...
    }

    public void somefunction()
    {
        Upgrade autoclickUpgrade = Upgrades.Where(p => p.Name == "Autoclicker").FirstOrDefault();

        if(autoclickUpgrade == null)
            throw new Exception("Could not find Autoclicker upgrade.");

        //do something with autoclickUpgrade
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove static from `string Naam`:

```
 public class Upgrades: MonoBehaviour {
        public struct Upgrade1{
            public const int Cost = 10;
            public const float Value = 0.1f;
            public string Naam = "Autoclicker";
       }

 }
```

When an object ( class, variable, method) is defined as `static` it can not be referenced through an instance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are on the right track, probably. Since the struct (type) that your add-on depends on may or may not exist, Reflection is the best way to go here.

Try Assembly.GetType(), or a related method, to attempt to load the type, check its existence, and iterate its members.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you both for the quick respond @mrjoltcola & @apomene!
I removed the static and added:


`Assembly assem = typeof(Upgrades).Assembly;
Type m_type = assem.GetType("Upgrades.Upgrade1");`

To the upgrade button script. However, I do not get any errors but when I Debug.Log(m_type) it does not log anything. When I type m_type. it does not return those variables.

Comment: I'm confused now, you accepted an answer that doesn't load anything dynamically, so did you post this comment before or after that?

Comment: You are right but he told me "it sounds like poorly thought out design." So I thought maybe I can better change it to his suggestion and from there move further along.